# special character in filename (\#033OA)

Tags: filenames, character-encoding, special-characters

I've got a slight problem with a very stubborn error during an rsync. It's caused by a file with a special character in its filename. There's been others but I could sort that out by doing some conversion in the encoding of the filename. However this one file I can't even find.

So here's what rsync says:

```
../.\#033OA.tex.pyD0MB" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

First thing one notices is that the character code can't be hex or octal so I've googled it and only found [this](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/screen-3.9.4/html_chapter/screen_11.html#SEC60). So it may be a `CURSOR UP` character (or not). I've tried

```
ls -la *`printf '\033OA'`*
```

to no avail. I've also tried piping the output of ls of that directory to `od` to no avail.

What else can I do? Or what character am I looking for anyway?

Thanks

Comment: Try `ls -b`, which should show C-style escapes

Comment: thanks... that helped... could move it with the help of printf then... if you repost this comment as answer, I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `-b` option to `ls`, which shows non graphical characters as C-style escape sequences.

Answer (score 3):

`ls -aq` will print all file names, with a `?` instead of each nonprintable character. On many unix variants, `ls -AB` or `ls -Ab` (check your man page) will print octal escapes. With `ls -aq`, you can use the displayed output as a shell pattern.

```
$ ls -Aq
.?OA.tex.pyD0MB
… more stuff …
$ mv -i .?OA.tex.pyD0MB weird-file
$ less weird-file
```

Another way to get at the file name somehow is to use your shell's completion: enter `mv .` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly until the weird name is inserted.

Comment: `ls -q` didn't show the file whereas `ls -b` did. maybe because its filename wasnt `[weird-character]OA.tex` but really `\`printf %b '\033OA'\`.tex`

Comment: @luxifer There's a `.` at the beginning of the file name, so you need `ls -Aq` or `ls -aq`. And if you use shell wildcards, you need to make the `.` explicit: `*` won't include the file but `.*` will.

Comment: no there wasn't! The output I posted was from rsync and it was the end of the line. Rsync first copys to `$DESTINATION/.$FILENAME` before it moves the file to it's correct name. Therefor at the source the file had no `.` at the beginning of its name. Also, as said, `ls -q` wouldn't have shown the file whereas `ls -b` did.